# Displaying different controls for different group of logged in people in mvc web API

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, html

I am working on an API in which I have different set of people who should have different set of controls displayed on their page depending on the role of the user.

I am using Custom filters to determine which users will have access to which pages and I am able to successfully do it but the issue is I have three link buttons in the masters page and only users with admin role should be able to see all the link buttons and remaining users will have only sign out button.

I have my master page as follows.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>@ViewBag.Title</title>
    @Styles.Render("~/Content/css")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr")
</head>
<body>
    <header>
        <div class="content-wrapper">
            <div class="float-left">

                <p class="site-title">
                    <a href="~/">
                        <img src= '@Url.Content("~/Images/logo.png")' /></a>
                </p>

            </div>
            <div class="float-right">
                <table>
                    @if (Request.IsAuthenticated)
                    {
                        <tr>                     
                            <td class="btn">@Html.ActionLink(@Html.Encode(User.Identity.Name).ToUpper() + "!!", "Index", "Admin")</td>
                            <td class="btn">@Html.ActionLink("Manage Users", "Index", "System_User")</td>
                            <td class="btn">@Html.ActionLink("Sign Out", "Logout", "User")</td>

                        </tr>
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        <tr>
                            <td class="User btn">
                                @Html.ActionLink("Sign In", "Login", "User")</td>
                        </tr>
                    }
                </table>
            </div>
        </div>
    </header>
    <div class="container">

        @RenderBody()
    </div>
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
    @RenderSection("scripts", required: false)
</body>
</html>
```

Custom Authorize class

```
public class CustomAuthorizeAttribute : AuthorizeAttribute
    {
        public bool IsAdmin { get; set; }

        protected override bool AuthorizeCore(HttpContextBase httpContext)
        {
            using (var cn = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=xyz.com;Initial Catalog=123$;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=abc;Password=$pqr"))
            {
                string _username = httpContext.User.Identity.Name;
                string _sql = @"SELECT [IsAdmin] FROM [dbo].[System_User] " +
                      @"WHERE [Username] = @u";
                var cmd = new SqlCommand(_sql, cn);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@u", _username);
                DataSet ds = new DataSet();
                SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter();
                cn.Open();
                da.SelectCommand = cmd;
                da.Fill(ds);




                if (ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count != 0)
                {
                    string admin = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["IsAdmin"].ToString();
                    if (admin == "True")
                    {
                        cmd.Dispose();
                        IsAdmin = true;
                        return IsAdmin;
                    }
                    return false;
                }
                return false;
            }

        }
    }
```

I tried using multiple master pages for different views, the issue is when an admin visits the page which as master page that of a normal user, obviously the admin will not have access to the three link buttons as long as the admin stays in that page.

Comment: Just add IsAdmin to your ViewBag, and use it in your View. By the way, why are you using SQL queries to get the data from database?

Comment: Is there a best way to get the data from database?
Do you mean LINQ?

Comment: Yes, entity framework and linq.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the answer I figured out

```
@if (Request.IsAuthenticated)
{
    <nav>
        <ul class="nav">
            @if(ViewContext.HttpContext.User.IsInRole("Admin"))
            {
            <li> @Html.ActionLink(User.Identity.Name, "Admin", "Home")
           <ul>
               <li>@Html.ActionLink("Products", "Products", "Home")</li>
            <li>  @Html.ActionLink("Add New User", "Register", "Account", routeValues: null, htmlAttributes: new { id = "registerLink" })</li>
               <li>@Html.ActionLink("Active Users", "ActiveUsers", "Home")</li>

            </ul>
               </li>
            }
            else{ <li> @Html.ActionLink(User.Identity.Name, "Index", "Home")</li>}


            @*<li>@Html.ActionLink("Home", "Index", "Home")</li>*@
            <li>@Html.ActionLink("About", "About", "Home")</li>
            <li>@Html.ActionLink("Contact", "Contact", "Home")</li>
             <li> @Html.ActionLink("Change Password", "Manage", "Account", routeValues: null, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "username", title = "Manage" })</li>
            <li> 
            @using (Html.BeginForm("LogOff", "Account", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "logoutForm" }))
    {
        @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
        <a href="javascript:document.getElementById('logoutForm').submit()">Log off</a>

    }
                </li>
        </ul>
    </nav>

}
else
{
    <ul class="nav">
        @*<li>@Html.ActionLink("Register", "Register", "Account", routeValues: null, htmlAttributes: new { id = "registerLink" })</li>*@
        <li>@Html.ActionLink("Log in", "Login", "Account", routeValues: null, htmlAttributes: new { id = "loginLink" })</li>
    </ul>
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Dayakar,

You could create a method that will query the database and evaluate whether they are an admin like you are right now. Then, you just add this code to the Master Page after the authenticated if block.

```
if (ExtensionMethods.IsAdmin) {
    // include the links here
}
```

This will show the links if the method evaluates to true. Otherwise, it won't show the links.

That's an awkward way of querying a database though. I would try to use [Entity Framework](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/creating-an-entity-framework-data-model-for-an-asp-net-mvc-application) instead.